# Как передать данные из editText одного фрагмента в список другого?

Tags: android

Есть два фрагмента. В одном лежит поле EditText, куда вводится текст, который после нажатия кнопки пополняет список в другом фрагменте (ListFragment). Как это реализовать?

Comment: Как связаны эти два фрагмента? Видны в один момент времени? Или один заменяет другой после нажатия кнопки? Находятся в одной активити?

Comment: После нажатия кнопки один заменяет другой, активити одна.